# Why are service layers good at all?

Tags: c#, laravel, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Let's imagine I'm using MVC. controller got the request from user. do the logic in controller and return the response.

People say that controllers don't do any logic, they simply give the incoming request to service and all the logic stays in service classes methods. But I don't understand why this is good.

**Argument 1)** people say this is good because you have skinny controllers instead of fat controllers, but who cares skinny controllers if it doesn't give you benefit?

**Argument 2)** your business logic is somewhere else and not coupled to controller. Why is this argument even worth mentioning? Okay, I have all the logic in service classes' methods and in my controllers they're two lines of code. What did that give me? Service classes are still huge. Is this some kind of benefit?

**Argument 3)** one engineer even told me that service layer is good because from service methods you return objects to controller and in controller we sometimes return json or some other format. He told me this is good if we have desktop/web/mobile application all together and we are writing api for them. but still doesn't make sense.

What people do and I hate is that they use repository and service (in service methods, they have business logic and repository classes method calls).

**Here is how I think**. If using service classes (I call it helpers), in a service method, there shouldn't be a thing related to framework. if there's fraemwork dependent code, then it's bad because all my business logic is tightly coupled to framework. What my friend advised is that I put get,insert,update eloquent calls in controller and pass the results to helper (service) which does the data modification. This way to test a helper (service) no need to inject repository or model at all. And why do we have to even need to test repository or model (it's already tested by the framework).

I just have to understand why service layer is going to help me. The thing is I've read so much, and none of the articles really say the real benefits. Is it possible we discuss pros and cons with examples?

Answer (score 1):

Abstraction.

The theory that most people subscribe to is that all functions should do one thing only and one thing well. Keeping this in mind, one huge controller method doesn’t make sense.

*but what about just using lots of private methods in your controller file?*

It’s arguably harder to debug private methods than public ones because you typically can’t access them to unit test them. Why not just make them public and still keep them in the same file? Because that’s not how we do things. Separation of concern is very important in the MVC model.

Here’s how a controller should work in MVC:

1. Take an input
2. Do *stuff* (doesn’t matter what that stuff is)
3. Output

The controller shouldn’t care about the business logic - complicated logic should just be a black box that *just works* as far as the controller is concerned.

Moreover, if you have external API calls, the controller should never be doing them directly. They should be hidden away in a `connectors` package and accessed via a service layer.

I think the main point of using a service layer is that if your business logic ever changes, your controller shouldn’t care. Your controller should be as “stupid” as possible.

In order to make each layer of your app as reliable and predictable as possible, you need to make sure each layer has a defined purpose - the controller shouldn’t be taking in inputs, doing complex logic, and giving outputs. Obviously if the logic is tiny then abstracting it is a bit of overkill but it’s a good habit to get into.

Finally, it makes debugging your code easier for other people. If you move on from this project and someone else has to pick up where you left off, if your code is all in one place then they will hate you. Finding bugs and making improvements is very hard when everything is all together. If you follow convention and separate your business logic away from your controller, you will make other people’s lives easier as they’ll know what to expect.

Basically, just do it. It’s a good practice to get into and will make your life easier in the future.

Comment: Thanks James, Is it possible if we chat about this ? it might take us long to finally understand it. if you don't mind of course.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/novaknole/65e4f0484a8173c0f3989e5246c69b18 this is my register function in controller and also auth service. take a look at registerUser function in my controller. I seperated them. I have no idea how it helps me though.

Comment: Good answer, James. You could add that building apps as services allows you to use them in a non-controller context in the future. Your service takes some parameters and returns an array result, and your HTTP controller just feeds in query string information and renders the result as JSON. If you want to use the service in a queue, or a console command, then you already have a software component that is amenable to this - and separately tested outside of an HTTP context.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give simple answer 
Try to write unitest for fat controller ...

It is better to test class or even interface method instead of controller method which returns view. Better to test method which have less preconditions and responsibility. Controller's methods is final method which intergate all logic. Http processing, Validation, business, and so on. For unit testing,debuging and reusing  it is better to keep this logical parts separately.